# url-Encode vs Base64 encoding ( usages)?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, query-string, base64, encodeuricomponent

I was wondering...

*(except the issue with the base64's plus'+' sign in query string  - which is translated to 'space' and can be solved by %2b)* :---> which is the preferred way to transfer data in query string?

Both functions can be used through the JS commands:

- `btoa`
- `encodeUriComponent`

so im asking myself(and you) :

**when** should I use **what** ? ( ive always used  `encodeUriCompoonent` - by instinct).

the problem that the definitions are different - but the implementations can be similar...

### edit

I think ive found the reason for asking.... ( and why nobody asked it before)

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**base64** is used to transfer binary data. *(not supported in IE, cant encode spacial chars.)*

**encodeURIComponent** only encodes  special characters.

An interesting thing is that you can't apply base64 to unicode strings without encodeURIComponent:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.btoa

Comment: like i said `the problem that the definitions are different - but the implementations can be similar...` -still didnt get an answer....:)

Comment: `the implementations can be similar` ? It has different purposes that are described in definitions.

Comment: I can use also **base64**  to transfer `userid=1` and also **encodeURIComponent** ... im looking for the difference.

Comment: Then no difference, really. But if you transfer Unicode data then you're obliged to use encodeURIComponent. And also base64 will take more space comparing to encodeURIComponent.

Comment: encodeURIComponent() will only take less space if you exclusively pass characters that won't be encoded (i.e. mostly alphanumeric) - anything actually encoded will take far more space than base64 would.

e.g. `btoa('::')` becomes `Ojo=` whereas `encodeURIComponent('::')` becomes `%3A%3A` - and baloons upwards with greater character counts.

Comment: @lucideer in any case more general than `btoa('::')` you need to do a 'btoa(encodeURIComponent(realWorldString))' or else btoa won't work. The case you depict is one in which the input to '::' does not even have one character outside plain ASCII. Even U+0100 breaks. As soon as you desire encoding (i.e. more than ASCII), you need encodeURIComponent anyway and the sizes are added up and comparison does not make much sense.

Comment: Your link is a dead link

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this is entirely dependent on your server-side application.

***'+'*** is not translated to ***'space'*** by the client - it is auto-translated to ***'space'*** by some server-side apps, largely for backward-compatibility reasons (conversely, some server-side apps will leave ***'+'*** as ***'+'*** in compliance with [RFC3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986) ).

As far as the client is concerned - `btoa()` and `encodeURIComponent()` (and `encodeURI()` and `escape()`) just encode a string of text into different abstracted strings according to different encoding or escaping algorithms - `btoa()` usually produces the smallest resultant string using **base64** encoding but [meze's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10267669/210865) re: unicode is worth taking into account here.

The important thing to note is what your server-side application (some ASP.NET-based setup in your case) then uses to decode that string back to it's original form.

Comment: Considering the necessity to use `encodeURIComponent()` for Unicode character > U+00FF anyway, the use case of `btoa()` and hence the suggested advantage of a smaller size, is very limited

Answer (score 0):

I use Base64 encoding when I want to convert byte array into a string, with ability to convert it back to byte array later.

UrlEncoding when I want a string to be placed safely within url.

Answer (score -1):

fwiw, I use base64 whenever I want to transport anything that CAN be unicode, between a server and a client. urlencode doesn't handle all unicode charachters all that well. It quickly gets a mess with all the percentage signs.

so, in short: expecting unicode input/output, always base64 the transportation.

Comment: I just saw the other answer by user meze. I don't know what he's talking about. I use base64 encoding exactly BECAUSE it handles unicode strings so well. Japanese, Chinese, Cyrillic input daily on a couple of my sites that gets transported this way.

Comment: Base64 works only with ASCII and encodeURIComponent does work with unicode. Try it in your browser: `window.btoa('✓ à la mode');`

Comment: aha, well, I have no idea of what btoa does. when I was talking about base64, I meant it as a general thing. I use it from PHP myself to send stuff up to the client.