# PHP can't read email address from $http post method of angular

Tags: php, angularjs

Everything works fine except email address. When i post email address to server and just echo it, recieve nothing. Only problem in @ symbol, rest are ok.

**angular:**

```
$http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://______.org/_____.php',
            data: {
                signInSubmitBTN: '',  email: 'joe@g.com'
            }
        }).success(function (data) {
            alert(data); //alert empty when joe@g.com but joeg.com is ok
        });
```

**PHP**

```
if (isset($_POST['signInSubmitBTN'])) {

$email = $_POST["email"];

echo $email;
}
```

**NOTE -** already configure app

```
app.config(function ($httpProvider, $httpParamSerializerJQLikeProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.unshift($httpParamSerializerJQLikeProvider.$get());
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8';
    })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode using base64:

```
signInSubmitBTN: '',  email: window.btoa('joe@g.com')
```

And don't forget to decode on  the server side using `atob()`

Comment: Thanks. another question encodeURIComponent(email), is it also an alternative for this or not.

Comment: Take a look at:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267597/url-encode-vs-base64-encoding-usages

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in back end to get POST data back in PHP.

```
if(isset($_POST)){

  $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");

 $request = json_decode($postdata);
  echo $request->email;
 }
```